# Prevent Spring from closing context after initializing context

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka

I am trying to make simple application for working with kafka. The purpose of application is to listen the kafka topic and react on messages from it (in this case is just log the message).

src/main/java/pkg/Application.java

```
package pkg;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args).close();
    }

    // Want to avoid creation of this bean
    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner applicationRunner() {
        return args -> {
            while (true) {
                TimeUnit.DAYS.sleep(1);
            }
        };
    }

    @Component
    public static class Listener {
        @KafkaListener(topics = "testTopic")
        public void listenBatch(String message) {
            LOGGER.info("Message: {}", message);
        }
    }
}
```

src/main/resources/application.properties

```
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=test_group
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.0.RELEASE"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json'

    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
}
```

The issue is that without workaround (`applicationRunner` bean) application is shutting down after initializing a context.

So the question is:
What is the proper way to prevent spring context from closing in my case?

Comment: Have you tried just not calling `close()` on the result of `SpringApplication.run(..)`?

Comment: @David you are right. The issue was in calling `close` method. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SpringApplication.run(..)` returns an `ApplicationContext` on which you call `close()`. Thus, the simple answer here is "don't do that".

Why is that correct? According to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-spring-application.html#boot-features-application-exit) Spring Boot automatically registers a shutdown hook to close the context if you use `SpringApplication`. Thus, you do not need to worry about explicitly closing the context like you normally do.